# ReactJS Left custom drawer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to build drawer in reactjs as shown in the image below. The text items in this list must also be scrollable.
Does anyone know about any built-in reactjs mui component for this?

you can find the image here

[image]

Comment: Post images with the inbuilt uploader. Don't post links to images.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and they are not letting me upload, instead they are themselves giving this link to my uploaded image.